# Comparing Dates in MongoDB Stored as Strings as MM/DD/YYYY format

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have dates in MongoDB stored in `runDate` as `MM/DD/YY` format. My goal is to get the records of the last n days.

```
const days = moment().subtract(200, "days").format("MM/DD/YYYY");

data.find({"runDate": {gte: "day"}})
```

I realize my code above is not always right. This is because I believe MongoDB does not know what format it is. How do I tell Mongo I need to compare for `MM/DD/YYYY` format?

Comment: Opinion wise: Don't save the date as string value in MongoDB document. This will make the query complex and not efficient especially when each time you need to query by certain date/range.

Comment: Thanks for this information, however this is not my database. Not much I can do about the format it is saved in.

Comment: I was thinking to just get everything from the database then just sort them at server level.

Comment: Not just an opinion as stated by @YongShun: You should **never** store date/time values as string, it's a design flaw. Store always proper `Date` objects.

Comment: I suggest you to use dayjs to compare and filter dates instead of momentjs as it is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment that you shouldn't store the Date value as a string in MongoDB.

Otherwise, you should convert the date string to the Date value via [`$dateFromString`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/#-datefromstring--aggregation-) and compare.

```
data.find({
  $expr: {
    $gte: [
      { 
        $dateFromString: {
          dateString: "$runDate",
          format: "%m/%d/%Y"
        } 
      },
      /* Date value */
    ]
  }
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not do the job. Thanks for the suggestion. I will do an alternate way and process data at server side.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake on my answer, have you try the format as: "%m/%d/%Y"?

Comment: No worries, I had updated the code before I tried initially. It does not work for some reason. I just decide to do the comparison with code.

Comment: Found the issue, dateFromString can only be used with aggregate.